# private в TS не переводится в символ решётки (#) в JS

Tags: javascript, классы, typescript

Объясните пожалуйста почему в классах TS, при указании `private` для поля/метода (далее ПМ), после преобразования в файл JS не стоит знак `#` перед ПМ?

[@AlexeyTen](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1420326/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8f%d1%86%d0%b8%d1%8f-typescript#comment2529275_1420326) дал такой комментарий, что в TS - это просто чисто "декаративный" и что нельзя просто взять и поменять одно на другое. И оставлена ссылка на [обсуждение этого вопроса в GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31670)

Там [лид разработки TS](https://github.com/RyanCavanaugh) даёт такой [ответ](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31670#issuecomment-497370201). Т.к. не понимал всех слов, потому переводил для себя с помощью гугл перводчика и сервиса Reverso и вот что получилось:

> Наш текущий план состоит в том, чтобы оставить текущее приватное поведение как есть
>
> Причины для этого:
>
> - Мы не вносим критические изменения без причины, и ничто внешнее не заставляет людей отказываться от времени компиляции `private`
> - Есть очень хорошие варианты использования приватности только во время компиляции:
>
>   - `private` поля могут быть прочитаны из модульных тестов (Я понимаю, что некоторые люди находят это лично неприятным, но это не универсально.)
>   - `private` поля имеют гораздо лучшую производительность во время выполнения в сценариях нижнего уровня
> - Многим людям не нравится синтаксис `#`, так зачем навязывать им его
> - Без `WeakMap` (которые есть не у всех сред выполнения) нет хороших эквивалентов понижения уровня для тяжёлого выполнения приватности
>
> Насчет трансформатора, почему бы нет? Их легко заменить с помощью регулярных выражений, если у вас есть мотивация

После долгих обсуждений [один из авторов](https://github.com/AnyhowStep) приводит в шутку такой [пример](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31670#issuecomment-578869054), который меня ещё больше смутил:

> Права человека:
>
> ```
> class Human {
>  #rights;
>
>  removeRights () {
>    console.log("No");
>  }
> }
>
> class Government {
>  takeawayRights (human) {
>    human.removeRights(); //No
>    human.rights = undefined; //Not allowed
>  }
> }
> ```
>
> Привелегии человека:
>
> ```
> class Human {
>  private privileges;
>
>  removePrivileges () {
>    console.log("No");
>  }
> }
>
> class Government {
>  takeawayPrivileges (human) {
>    human.removePriveleges(); //No
>    human.privileges = undefined; //OK!
>  }
> }
> ```

И получается, что не смотря на то что ПМ `private`, я всё равно могу спокойно к нему обращаться напрямую и менять как вздумается

И если честно, прочитал там многое и хоть не до конца, но +- понял как именно работает `private`, но я так и не понял: Почему он так работает? В чём причина того, чтобы `private` в TS не работает как `#` в JS

Если сможете пояснить на пальцах буду очень рад :)

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137127/discussion-on-question-by-eziomercer-private--ts-----).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> И получается, что не смотря на то что ПМ private, я всё равно могу спокойно к нему обращаться напрямую и менять как вздумается

Именно так. TS изначально задуман как надстройка над JS которой не существует в рантайме. Так что доступ к `private` полям проверяется только в момент компиляции, но если вы как-то сумели «обойти» компилятор, то в скомпилированном JS `private` поле абсолютно не отличается от `public`.

В вашем последнем примере компилятор TS будет ругаться на строчку `human.privileges = undefined;` ошибкой `Property 'privileges' is private and only accessible within class 'Human'.`.

Comment: _В вашем последнем примере компилятор TS будет ругаться на строчку_ - не будет, потому что у параметра не задан тип, по умолчанию посчитает `any` а для any - все проверки пройдут. В рантайме же все выполнится

Comment: @Grundy ну я имел в виду если нормально типы прописать

Comment: Тогда да, но в примере типы опущены :)