# Почему в JS классах не используется ключевое слово private

Tags: javascript, классы

Давно задаюсь вопросом: Почему же вместо многим привычного ключегого слова `private`, в JS классах, решили использовать именно знак `#`?

Особо так и не искал до сих пор, а при простых поисках в основом говорят что вот в JS используется `#` вместо `private` и дальше примеры как с ним работать, но не дают ответа на вопрос **Почему?**

Сегодня решил всё же найти ответ, т.к. был уверен, что не я один задаюсь этим вопросом. Ну и впоисках наткнулся на целый [ЧЗВ](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/main/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md) (на английском) посвящённый этой теме

Comment: Чисто ради интереса, не из-за моего вопроса появился такой интерес к TS?)

Comment: Ну если честно TS-ом я увлекаюсь давно) Но причина интереса к этому приставучему слову `private` появился после того как узнал, что `private` в TS не переводится в `#` в JS?, если это был ваш вопрос, то ответ да :) + недавно на работе с ребятами обсуждали почему же в JS не используется это `private` и никто не ответил, ну после вопроса что я упомянул решил раз и навсегда закрыть этот вопрос, чтобы в голове не крутился. У меня бывает, возникает мелкий вопрос, но не охота гуглить, особенно, когда первые ответы гугла не дают ответа и я вроде и забиваю, но вопрос всё время в голове возникает

Comment: @OliverPatterson Но вообще странно, что вы задали этот вопрос тут, потому что тут ничего к TS не относится вам скорее надо было задать его [тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1420542/private-%d0%b2-ts-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d0%bf%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%81%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%bb-%d1%80%d0%b5%d1%88%d1%91%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-js) :)

Comment: Да я просто заметил ту тему и эту и решил уже в "новой" спросить :). Я вот только недавно начал вникать в TS, всегда было интересно, но руки не доходили.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

На вопрос **Почему именно знак `#`?** даётся такой [ответ](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/main/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md#why-was-the-sigil--chosen-among-all-the-unicode-code-points):

> Никто не пришёл и не сказал, что `#` — это самая красивая, интуитивно понятная вещь для обозначения приватного состояния. Вместо этого это был скорее процесс исключения:
>
> - `@` был первоначальным фаворитом, но его забрали декораторы. TC39 рассматривал возможность замены символов декораторов и приватных состояний, однако комитет решил отложить существующее использование транспилеров пользователями.
> - `_` вызвало бы проблемы совместимости с существующим JavaScript кодом, который долгое время допускал `_` в начале идентификатора или (публичного) имени свойства.
> - Другие символы, которые могут быть использованы в качестве инфиксных операторов, но не префиксных операторов, гипотетически возможны, такие как `%`, `^`, `&`, `?`, учитывая, что наш синтаксис немного уникален — `х.%у`, в настоящее время не является допустимым, так что не было бы никакой двусмысленности. Однако сокращение может привести к проблемам с [ASI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion), например, следующее будет выглядеть как использование инфиксного оператора:
>
>   ```
>   class Foo {
>     %x;
>     method() {
>       calculate().my().value()
>       %x.print()
>     }
>   }
>   ```
>
>   Здесь пользователь, вероятно, намеревался вызвать метод печати для `this.%x`, но вместо этого будет использоваться оператор деления по модулю!
> - Можно использовать и другие [кодовые точки](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_point) Unicode, которых нет в ASCII или IDStart, но многим пользователям может быть сложно их ввести т.к. их нет на обычных клавиатурах.
>
> В конце концов, единственными другими вариантами являются более длинные последовательности знаков препинания, которые кажутся неоптимальными по сравнению с одним символом.

На вопрос **Почему не используется ключевое слово `private`?** даётся такой [ответ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#automatic_semicolon_insertion):

> Такое объявление используется в других языках (особенно в Java) и подразумевает, что доступ будет осуществляться с помощью `this.x`. Предполагая, что это не так (см. выше), в JavaScript это автоматически создаст или получит доступ к общедоступному полю, а не выдаст ошибку. Это основной потенциальный источник ошибок или невидимого создания публичных полей, которые должны были быть частными.
>
> Он также допускает симметрию между объявлением и доступом, как и для публичных полей:
>
> ```
> class A {
>  pub = 0;
>  #priv = 1;
>  m() {
>    return this.pub + this.#priv;
>  }
> }
> ```

Так вот если с первым вопросом всё понятно, то ко второму у меня было куча вопросов. Отсылка **(см. выше)**, если я правильно понял, отсылается к одному из этих двух (ну или обоих) пунктов. Сначала дам их переводы:

1. Почему нет доступа к `this.x`? ([Оригинал](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/main/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md#why-isnt-access-thisx))

> Наличие частного поля с именем `x` не должно препятствовать тому, чтобы было публичное поле с именем `x`, поэтому доступ к частному полю не может быть простым поиском.
>
> Это проблема только в JavaScript из-за отсутствия статических типов. Статически типизированные языки используют объявления типов, чтобы различать внешние-публичные/внутренне-приватные случаи без необходимости символа. Но язык с динамической типизацией не имеет достаточно статической информации, чтобы различать эти случаи.

2. Почему бы не выполнить проверку типа получателя во время выполнения, чтобы определить, следует ли обращаться к частному или публичному полю с именем `x`? ([Оригинал](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/main/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md#why-not-do-a-runtime-check-on-the-type-of-the-receiver-to-determine-whether-to-access-the-private-or-public-field-named-x))

> Семантика доступа к свойствам уже сложна, и мы не хотим замедлять каждый доступ к свойствам только для того, чтобы добавить эту функцию.
>
> Это также позволило бы обмануть методы класса, чтобы они работали с открытыми полями неэкземпляров, как если бы они были частными полями экземпляров. К примеру посмотрите этот [комментарий](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields/issues/14#issuecomment-153050837)

Внимательно изучив указанный комментарий я наконец-то осознал почему не ввели `private` как это принято в других языках. Ниже будет первая часть комментария:

> Рассмотрим такой сценарий:
>
> ```
> class X {
>     private a;
>
>     constructor(a) { this.a = a }
>
>     swap(otherX) {
>         let otherA = otherX.a;
>
>         otherX.a = this.a;
>         this.a = otherA;
>
>         return otherA;
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> Давайте вызовем `swap` с экземпляром `X` в качестве аргумента:
>
> ```
> let x1 = new X(1);
> let x2 = new X(2);
> x1.swap(x2); // --> 2
> ```
>
> В этом случае ссылка на `otherX.a` должна обращаться к частному полю с именем `a`, согласны?
>
> Что, если мы вызовем `swap` с объектом, который не является экземпляром `X`?
>
> ```
> let x1 = new X(1);
> let x2 = {a: 3};
> x1.swap(x2); // --> TypeError или 3?
> ```
>
> Без указания типа для параметра `otherX` у нас нет никакого способа сообщить компилятору, означает ли `otherX.a`:
>
> - Найти поле с названием `a` у `otherX` или
> - Найти приватное поле с названием `a` у `otherX`

Если хочется спросить **Почему бы просто obj.x не всегда ссылаться на приватное поле внутри класса, который объявляет приватное поле x?**, то на это даётся такой [ответ](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-class-fields/blob/main/PRIVATE_SYNTAX_FAQ.md#why-not-just-always-have-objx-refer-to-a-private-field-inside-of-a-class-which-declares-a-private-field-x):

> Методы класса часто манипулируют объектами, которые не являются экземплярами класса. Было бы удивительно, если бы код `obj.x` внезапно перестал ссылаться на публичное поле `x` объекта `obj`, когда `obj` не должен быть экземпляром класса, просто потому, что этот код случайно появился где-то внутри класса, который объявляет приватное поле с именем `x`, возможно, глубоко внутри указанного класса.

Если есть у вас время и желание, то можете прочитать [всё обсуждение](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields/issues/14) на счёт этого вопроса.

Если в кратце, то люди очень сильно были недовольны таким решением и предлагали самые разные способы и методы как бы это сделать по привычнее. По моему беглому взгляду почти по всем комментариям, я могу выделить 3 типа предложений:

1. Использовать `@` вместо `#`
2. Использовать другой синтаксис но с `#` или что-то вообще новое. Например что-то типа `this#x` (без точки). Или `this->x`. Или например объявить c помощью `private`, но обращаться через `this.#x`
3. Пусть во время выполнения будут всякие проверки, которые позволят точно определить это приватное или публичное поле

И почти все ответы на эти предложения таковы:

1. Этот знак используют декораторы
2. Приводились примеры, когда предлагаемый синтаксис ломался или приводил в непонимаение того почему программист использует в одном случае такой синтаксис, а в этом другой
3. Алгоритмы обращения к полям на данный момент очень хорошо оптимизированы и никто не собирается вставлять в них проверки всяких условий для каждого обращения к полю класса

Единнственное мне как и многим другим комментаторам не ясно, что будет придумано для `protected` или других ключевых слов? Неужели мы должны будем писать кучу символов каждый раз перед названиями?

Лично мне всё это дало чёткое понимание положения и выбора авторов, надеюсь это так же будет полезно и тем кто задаётся этим вопросом :)